# Install Redis-Server on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS minimal

Tags: 16.04, server, services, openvz, redis

I have got a question and hope that somebody can help me. I own a vServer on a OpenVZ basis (I hate the kernel limitation) and can't install Redis.

What do I do:

- Clean install Ubuntu 16.04. LTS minimal
- Login as root
- run: `apt update`
- run: `apt upgrade`

(I don't know if this is relevant, but this appears during the process:

> Installing new version of config file /etc/systemd/system.conf ...
>   addgroup: The group `systemd-journal' already exists as a system
>   group. Exiting. [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/var.conf:14] Duplicate line for
>   path "/var/log", ignoring. Failed to validate path /var/run/sshd: Too
>   many levels of symbolic links Failed to validate path /var/run/sudo:
>   Too many levels of symbolic links Failed to validate path
>   /var/run/sudo/ts: Too many levels of symbolic links (Reading database
>   ... 16369 files and directories currently installed.)

- run: `apt install redis-server`

Problem appears:

> Setting up redis-server (2:3.0.6-1) ...
>
> fchownat() of /run/redis failed: Invalid argument
>
> insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc2.d/S15ssh_gen_host_keys
>
> Job for redis-server.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status redis-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
>
> invoke-rc.d: initscript redis-server, action "start" failed.
>
> ...
>
> Process: 11845 ExecStopPost=/bin/run-parts --verbose /etc/redis/redis-server.p       ost-down.d (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> Process: 11839 ExecStartPost=/bin/run-parts --verbose /etc/redis/redis-server.       post-up.d (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> Process: 11837 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exi       ted, status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> Process: 11833 ExecStartPre=/bin/run-parts --verbose /etc/redis/redis-server.p       re-up.d (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced key-value ....
>
> systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Unit entered ....
>
> systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Failed with r....
>
> Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
>
> dpkg: error processing package redis-server (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>
> Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
>
> Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.9) ...
>
> Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
>
> Errors were encountered while processing:
>    redis-server
>
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
>
> W: Operation was interrupted before it could finish

- run: `systemctl status redis-server.service`

> redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store    Loaded: loaded
>   (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset:
>   enabled)    Active: activating (start-post) since Mon 2018-11-19
>   19:41:53 CET; 54s ago
>        Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
>              man:redis-server(1)   Process: 11966 ExecStopPost=/bin/run-parts --verbose
>   /etc/redis/redis-server.post-down.d (code=exited, status=0/SUCC
>   Process: 11978 ExecStartPost=/bin/run-parts --verbose
>   /etc/redis/redis-server.post-up.d (code=exited, status=0/SUCCE
>   Process: 11976 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
>   (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)   Process: 11972
>   ExecStartPre=/bin/run-parts --verbose /etc/redis/redis-server.pre-up.d
>   (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS    CGroup:
>   /system.slice/redis-server.service
>              └─11977 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
>
> systemd[1]: Starting Advanced key-value store...
>
> run-parts[11972]: run-parts: executing /etc/redis/redis-server.pre-up.d/00_example
>
> run-parts[11978]: run-parts: executing /etc/redis/redis-server.post-up.d/00_example
>
> systemd[1]: redis-server.service: PID file /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid not readable (

After that I can't start Redis-Server (failed because a timeout was exceeded). What can I do to fix this problem? I saw many threads about redis in this forum, but the solutions didn't help me. Sorry for my bad english. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! Run commands `ls -lah /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid` and `ls -lah /var/run/redis/` then show returns for both here.

Comment: ls: cannot access '/var/run/redis/redis-server.pid': No such file or directory

Comment: total 0 | drwxrwsr-x 2 root root 40 . | rrwxr-xr-x 13 root root 440 ..

Comment: try with root user run `chmod -R 777 /var/run/redis/` then run redis server again.

Comment: Now `-rw-r--r-- 1 redis root 6 Nov 19 20:07 /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid`

Comment: And `total 4.OK` `drwxrwsrwx 2 root root 60 .` `drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 440 ..` `-rw-r--r-- 1 redis root 6 redis-server.pid`

Comment: As i see `redis-server.pid` is created. Redis still not work?

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: hmm, redis works when I install it before the first `apt update && apt upgrade`. So something is wrong within the upgrade

Comment: When I upgrade after the install of redis, redis is still working. But when I send the `reboot` command, the server doesn't reboot anymore and I have to reinstall the image.

Comment: Hi @Firehead! Our Ubuntu 16.04 server automatically updated itself at 2018-11-20 04:00 CET, and SSH stopped to work. It could to be somewhat related to your issue as we run two Redis instances on that server. What have you done to get a connection to your server again? Do you have errors related to `systemd-tmpfiles` in your log files?

Answer (score 3):

To fix your error: **Install Redis as non-root user.**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential tcl
```

### Download and Extract the Source Code

```
cd /tmp
```

Now, download the latest stable version of Redis. This is always available at a stable download URL:

```
curl -O http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
```

Unpack the tarball by typing:

```
tar xzvf redis-stable.tar.gz
```

Move into the Redis source directory structure that was just extracted:

```
cd redis-stable
```

### Build and Install Redis

Compiling dependencies:

```
cd deps
sudo make hiredis jemalloc linenoise lua geohash-int
cd ..
```

Compile the Redis binaries by typing:

```
make
```

After the binaries are compiled, run the test suite to make sure everything was built correctly. You can do this by typing:

```
make test
```

This will typically take a few minutes to run. Once it is complete, you can install the binaries onto the system by typing:

```
sudo make install
```

Begin by creating the redis user and group. This can be done in a single command by typing:

```
sudo adduser --system --group --no-create-home redis
```

Now, we can create the /var/lib/redis directory by typing:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/redis
```

We should give the redis user and group ownership over this directory:

```
sudo chown redis:redis /var/lib/redis
```

Adjust the permissions so that regular users cannot access this location:

```
sudo chmod 770 /var/lib/redis
```

### Starting Redis

Start up the systemd service by typing:

```
sudo systemctl start redis
```

Check that the service had no errors by running:

```
sudo systemctl status redis
```

Source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/redis-stable/src'
    CC Makefile.dep
    CC adlist.o
In file included from adlist.c:34:0:
zmalloc.h:50:31: fatal error: jemalloc/jemalloc.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:232: recipe for target 'adlist.o' failed
make[1]: *** [adlist.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/redis-stable/src'
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: try run: `cd deps` `sudo make hiredis jemalloc linenoise lua geohash-int` `cd ..` `sudo make install` separately

Comment: thanks, I will try this later, server refuses connection, don't know why :D

Comment: that didn't work neither -- make test: [exception]: Executing test client: couldn't open socket: no buffer space available.
couldn't open socket: no buffer space available...

Comment: try run `redis-cli` in command-line to check installation.. Redis socket you may setup separately (this is another question related redis setup. Example: https://guides.wp-bullet.com/how-to-configure-redis-to-use-unix-socket-speed-boost/)

Comment: result is: `Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused`